# excluding ignore from .gitignore file

Tags: git, gitignore

My `.gitignore` file is:

```
precompiled

!deployments
```

I want to exclude the `./precompiled` directory, but not `./deployments/xxx.war/WEB-INF/application/precompiled`, more precisely I want to include EVERYTHING in ./deployments folder...

I tried with several combinations (`!./deployments/**/*`, `./precompiled/**/*`, etc.) with no luck.

How can I do this?

Comment: the solution I've found so far is to include a .gitignore file inside ./precompiled directory... I wonder is there's a better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
/precompiled
```

This will exclude only the `precompiled` folder at the root, not the `precompiled` subfolders

Comment: I can't believe I haven't tried that... I hate to do it, but I'll accept your answer...

Comment: You shouldn't hate to accept help or answer, we're all in need of it :)